# My Meteor app keeps crashing, here's the error I get

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've installed Meteor for Windows. Since I'm using Windows, I can't install the Atmosphere 3rd party packages using Meteorite. So I had to follow the instructions here:

which can be found: http://www.discovermeteor.com/2013/03/20/using-meteor-and-atmopshere-on-windows/

If you’ve made it this far, you’ve got a running meteor executable on your Windows OS and you’re rearing to go. If you’ve spent much time in the community, you’ve probably realised that there’s this awesome collection of 3rd party packages called Atmosphere. To use Atmosphere packages, you need to run Meteorite; but Meteorite doesn’t run on Windows either! [^meaculpa]

Unfortunately, there’s no great answer to this problem as of this writing. However, if you absolutely need to use them, the process is like this:

Create a subdirectory of your project called packages/.
Figure out what packages you need (remember that packages have dependencies, but you can see them on the package’s atmosphere page. For example, here are the Router’s dependencies). Alternatively, you can look in the app’s smart.lock file in the dependencies section, if it’s already been resolved by Meteorite on another machine.
Install each package into packages/, directly from git.
NOTE: Many packages require you to run `git submodule update --init` inside them.
SECOND NOTE: most packages are named meteor-X in git (e.g. meteor-router), but need to be installed into a directory called X.
Run meteor where we tell you to run mrt.
This simulates, more or less, exactly what Meteorite does. So if you are following along with one of our examples, you should be able to get things working.

So I created my packages folder, cloned the packages, renamed the folders to match the name in the smart.json files for them. So meteor-router becomes "router" etc. Now when I run my app, I get this message:

```
=> Errors prevented startup: Exception while bundling application: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\newfrapp\packages\HTML5-History-API\HTML5-History-API\history.iegte8.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:338:18)
    at Object.fs.openSync (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\lib\node_modules\fstream\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:68:26)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:182:15)
    at _.extend.add_file (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:221:27)
    at self.api.add_files (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:145:16)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:78:11)
    at self.api.add_files (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:144:11)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:78:11)
    at Object.self.api.add_files (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:143:9)
    at null.on_use_handler (C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\newfrapp\packages\HTML5-History-API\package.js:6:7)
    at _.extend.use (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:483:11)
    at self.api.use (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:133:21)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:78:11)
    at Object.self.api.use (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:129:9)
    at _.extend.init_from_app_dir [as on_use_handler] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\packages.js:238:11)
    at _.extend.use (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:483:11)
    at Object.exports.bundle (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:897:12)
    at C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\run.js:698:26
    at exports.inFiber (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\fiber-helpers.js:24:12)
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I missed a crucial thing

NOTE: Many packages require you to run git submodule update --init inside them.

after doing this, everything worked fine.